# How do I get my code to analyse parts of my table that meet a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement

I'm new to Python and have one small issue with my code. It works the way I want, but I only need it to work on certain rows of my original csv table.

An example of the table is:
[image]

I need my code to only run on the rows that are chromosomes. I tried to use an 'if' statement, but it didn't quite work. I have a list that pulls out the name, accession, start, stop and locus tag, since this is the info I need.
I then iterate this list in a loop over my original file to get the data out like so:

```
def extractinfo(file_path):

    with io.open(file_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        # skips over the first line
        file.readline()
        # make an empty list
        SSL_list = list()
        # read through the whole file line by line
        for line in file.readlines():
            # separates by comma, pulls out specific headings as a list
            SSL = line.split(",")
            # convert the number string to an integer
            start = int(SSL[2])
            stop = int(SSL[3])
            # replace double quotes with nothing (use single quotes to differentiate)
            locustag = SSL[7].replace('"', "")
            ID = SSL[1].replace('"', "")
            name = SSL[0]
            # adds start, stop and locus tags to the end of the empty list every time it loops
            SSL_list.append((start, stop, locustag, ID, name))
        return SSL_list

def extract_seq(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        genome_sequence = str()
        # True runs forever
        while True:
            # skips lines, if the line starts with origin, it stops, leaving us a line after
            line = file.readline()
            if line.startswith("ORIGIN"):
                break
        for line in file.readlines():
            # replace spaces with nothing
            line = line.replace(" ", "")
            # starts at 0, continues until the end of the line (genome sequence)
            for i in range(0, len(line)):
                # checks if chararacters are actg
                if line[i] in "actg":
                    genome_sequence += (line[i])
    return genome_sequence

def extract_genes(SSL_list, genome_sequence):
    for start, stop, locustag, ID in SSL_list:
        # extracts start:stop gene from the sequence

        if start > stop:
            gene_substring = genome_sequence[0:start] + genome_sequence[stop:]
        else:
            gene_substring = genome_sequence[start:stop]
        if len(gene_substring) == 0:
            print(f"problem gene:{ID} {locustag}")
            exit(1)

        # store in file
        with open(end_file + "/" + ID + "+" + locustag + ".txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(gene_substring)
```

I inserted an if statement 'if name == "chromosome"' at the start of the for loop, but it didn't do what I wanted. Any help would be great

Comment: I believe there is an issue in the indentation of the code in the question. Could you fix that to make it more clear?

Comment: @Zingerella is that better? :)

Comment: Yes. Does extract_seq serve any purpose other than reading a txt file that has the genome sequence? I believe your sequence reading works well, but the loop that goes over each row is where you want to skip. Is that done in extract_genes? And is SSL_list the table with your excel data?

Comment: So extract_seq goes through my text file and only pulls out the genes that have listed start and stop positions from a table like the one i screenshotted. SSL_list is from another function that pulls out the relevant info i need from that table and puts it into a list so that I can loop it over my file to get my relevant info out. I hope that makes sense? If not I can add it to my question?

Comment: Alright so you're targeting the variable `name`. Is that available in SSL_list because that's where you want to skip? In the question you say 
> I have a list that pulls out the name, accession, start, stop and locus tag, since this is the info I need
but in the for loop you have `for start, stop, locustag, ID in SSL_list` so where is the name variable going?

Comment: I've added my code for SSL_list, this is where name is yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that name is added to the SSL_list but not extracted in the for loop:
`SSL_list.append((start, stop, locustag, ID, name))` vs `for start, stop, locustag, ID in SSL_list:`

You are very close to the answer. just add the name variable when extracting the variables in the for loop and implement the if condition as such:

```
def extract_genes(SSL_list, genome_sequence):
    for start, stop, locustag, ID, name in SSL_list:
        if 'chromosome' in name:
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using pandas for making of the table. In pandas if you want to keep only some part of your data, you can filter out the rows by using the following syntax:

```
genome_sequence[genome_sequence["#Name"]=="chromosome"]
```

Which will give you a subset of your data. It's just one small example. You can also do all other sorts of things using pandas, and it will be much faster than using loops.

Comment: I am using pandas to make my final csv table, but this is in another script. I'm a bit confused as to where this would go in the script? I've added my SSL_list function to help anyone reading